# Is static inner class thread safe inside another java class?

Tags: java, static, thread-safety, inner-classes

For collection of smaller helper utility classes, I have created a general `class MyUtils`:

```
// MyUtils.java
public final class MyUtils
{
  public static class Helper1 {};
  public static class Helper2 {};
//...
}
```

This helper classes from inside `MyUtils` will be used in the other files of the package:

```
// MyClass1.java
public class MyClass1
{
  private MyUtils.Helper1 help1 = new MyUtils.Helper1();
  public void method ()
  {
    private MyUtils.Helper2 help2 = new MyUtils.Helper2();
  }
}
```

To let them accessible, I have made them  `static` inside `MyUtils` (which doesn't have any data/function member of its own). My code is thread safe **before** creating `MyUtils`.

My worry is, by making these `inner` classes `static`will they remain **thread safe**, when their multiple instances will exist across the files ? Or is their any **bad implication** am I missing due to making them `static` ?

**Edit**: I am not touching any shared variable inside the `helper` classes. My only concern was that will the instance of the `static` classes be thread safe (since they are `static`).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're asking whether these is any bad implication of going from:

```
public class Helper1 {}
```

...to:

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static class Helper1 {}
}
```

Then no, there is not.  The `static` keyword in this case is just "promoting" the nested inner class to a top-level class, so that you can instantiate it without needing an enclosing instance of `MyUtils`.  Here is a passable article on the subject:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html

In essence, doing `public static class X` on a nested inner-class is the same as doing `public class X` in a standard top-level class.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 7):

There is no meaning to a "class" itself being thread-safe or not thread safe. Therefore, whether or not it is static is irrelevant.

When someone refers to a class being thread-safe or not thread-safe, they really mean that the functionalities provided by that class are thread-safe or not. Accordingly, it's what the inner classes do themselves that actually makes the difference.

There's nothing inherent about methods that make them unsafe to be reentrant. Problems arise when you start accessing shared variables, etc. So, for example, a member of the class accessed by the methods needs to be synchronized appropriately. But if the methods don't store any state, etc., then there's nothing stopping you from using them across multiple threads.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to guard the access to `help1` since this is an instance level (shared) variable.
While `help2` is safe if you dont allow it to skip the method.

There is nothing special about the static classes and instance created out of it. 
Same rules of thread safety applies to instances of static classes also which applies to normal cases.

Answer (score 0):

static methods and inner classes don't have any access to the variables of their dynamic counter part, and consequently can't use monitors/synchronize on an instance of their parent class.  Of course this doesn't mean that declaring them and using them is inherently non-thread safe.  It's just that if you need to synchronize any of those static methods on an instance of the parent class, then you need to be sure that you synchronize/lock *before* entering them or else you must explicitly pass a reference to a parent instance into them.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer. Making `MyUtils` an `interface` is more cleaner design, as I can get away with the `static` identifienr from the `helper` classes